# How to read file more than once C

Tags: c, file-upload

I am trying to store a list of words from a file into a char**. I am not to assume a max number of lines or a max number of characters. So to combat this, I decided to do a run through of the .txt file to find the number of lines and the maximum number of characters so I can allocate memory to  char** list.

However, when I used GDB to debug my program, it skips over the second runthough of the file to store in the words. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it? Thanks!

```
void readFile(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    char** list;
    char c;
    int wordLine = 0, counter = 0, i;
    int maxNumberOfChars = 0, numberOfLines = 0, numberOfChars = 0;

    myFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!myFile)
    {
        printf("No such file or directory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }

    while((c = fgetc(myFile)) !=EOF)
    {
        numberOfChars++;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            if(maxNumberOfChars < numberOfChars)
                maxNumberOfChars += numberOfChars + 1;

            numberOfLines++;
        }
    }

    fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    list = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numberOfLines);

    for(i = 0; i < wordLine ; i++)
        list[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*maxNumberOfChars);


    while((c = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n' && counter > 0)
        {
            list[wordLine][counter] = '\0';
            wordLine++;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else if(c != '\n')
        {
            list[wordLine][counter] = c;
            counter++;
        }
    } 
    fclose(myFile);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use fseek to reset the read-pointer of the file before your second loop.

Add something like this

```
fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

or

```
rewind(myFile);
```

thanks to @ThomasPadron-McCarthy.

Comment: Or rewind(myFile), which is a bit shorter both to type and read.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works, do you mind taking a look on why I am getting a seg fault on the first element my program is trying to store in?

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo It is always a good idea to debug such things yourself for some time. The learn-effect is much more significant like that. If you're stuck even after using `gdb` post a new question with a simplified version of your code producing the segfault.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I did use GDB, that's how I know the seg fault is happening at the very first element. That means I incorrectly allocated my memory. I am new to dynamically allocating memory to char**.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, your technique is bad because it is very slow. You can just allocate some memory and then use realloc if you need more.

2nd: you can use stat() on a file to know the size. You won't know the number of lines in it but it could be useful.

3rd: you can use fseek() to move the cursor back to the beginning of the file, and in general to any position within the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use rewind(myFile) before reading again.

```
rewind(myFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

but you don't need to read the whole file just to find out the number of chars. You can use this structure

```
struct stat file_stat;
fstat(file_id, &file_stat);
int size_to_read = file_stat.st_size - 1;
```

you don need to know the number of lines, because you can can use realloc on line:

```
list=realloc(list,(sizeof(char*)));
```